# Effect of pinch & zoom on height/width of image

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, winrt-xaml

I have pinch & zoom effect on an image. Is there a way I can reflect the changes in height and width of that image? I want to store the changes user has made to the size of image for later use.

or is there any other way I can make my image resizable for user that can allow me to save its width and height?

EDIT: The code I have is:

```
private void ResourceImage_ManipulationDelta(object sender, ManipulationDeltaRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Point flipViewScreenCoords = models_list.TransformToVisual(Window.Current.Content).TransformPoint(new Point(0, 0));
        Image currentImage = sender as Image;
        Point currentImageCoords = currentImage.TransformToVisual(Window.Current.Content).TransformPoint(new Point(0, 0));
        CompositeTransform transform = currentImage.RenderTransform as CompositeTransform;
        if ((currentImageCoords.X + currentImage.Width < flipViewScreenCoords.X + models_list.ActualWidth) && e.Delta.Translation.X > 0)
        {
            transform.TranslateX += e.Delta.Translation.X;
        }
        if (currentImageCoords.X > flipViewScreenCoords.X && e.Delta.Translation.X < 0)
        {
            transform.TranslateX += e.Delta.Translation.X;
        }
        if (currentImageCoords.Y + currentImage.Height < flipViewScreenCoords.Y + models_list.ActualHeight && e.Delta.Translation.Y > 0)
        {
            transform.TranslateY += e.Delta.Translation.Y;
        }
        if (currentImageCoords.Y > flipViewScreenCoords.Y && e.Delta.Translation.Y < 0)
        {
            transform.TranslateY += e.Delta.Translation.Y;
        }
        transform.ScaleX *= e.Delta.Scale;
        transform.ScaleY *= e.Delta.Scale;
    }
```

I have my image inside a flipview and the image is movable but should not leave the dimensions of flipview therefore I am using the if/else statements in this code. Now I am looking for a way to save the changed width/height of the image. Something like currentImage.Width = ??

Comment: Of course it can all be done, but I think you need to ask a more specific question.

Comment: Are you looking for a way to scale the image on screen or are you already using some technique to do it and looking to find what the scaled dimensions are or perhaps find out how to save these values? If you want to save them - do you want to save just the width and height or save a scaled image to a file, stream or a byte array?

Comment: Well, the width would be currentImage.ActualWidth * transform.ScaleX and the height would be currentImage.ActualHeight * transform.ScaleY.